# wordpress site showing warrning in some section

Tags: wordpress

my wordpress site is running ok but in some section this warning is shown

Warning: Parameter 2 to gdlr_core_page_builder::search_page_builder() expected to be a reference, value given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 287

wordpress ver:5.4.1

i deactive all plugin and active one by one and found when i deactive one of the plugin (Goodlayers Core
) not showning error anymore but all element of site is disappear because it's core of theme it seems.

Comment: This is a plugin issue. I would reach out to the developer of the plugin to fix this - however, check your `wp-config.php` for `WP_DEBUG`. If that is set to TRUE, set it to FALSE. This will hide this type of warning from the front end.

Answer (score 1):

The error describe itself.

From somewhere the 2nd parameter of the  function gdlr_core_page_builder::search_page_builder() is passed as value which should be a reference.

The error showing in file class-wp-hook.php on line 287 because of there is some hook is added into the above function.

You can contact that plugin author who will fix this issue if it is exist and release that plugin update.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plugin issue. However, you can simply disable the displayed warning by adding the below lines of code in wp-config.php file.

Locate your file under cPanel FileManager:
/home1/yoursitename/public_html/wp-config.php

Add the below lines of code to hide the displayed warning:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set('error_reporting',E_ALL);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, fixed by removing vars passed by reference (`&$`) on the file `/wp-content/plugins/goodlayers-core/framework/function/page-builder.php`:

- open the file
- search for `&$`, replace by `$`
- save, refresh website (clear cache if needed), error is gone